# java class/interface adapter question

Tags: java, oop

I have a toughie I'm trying to wrap my head around. I have some public interfaces and some package-private classes as shown below.

Basically my package private class (called `UltraDecoder` below) needs some grungy decode logic to decode data and perform some operations on it for its own internal use. However I would also like to make use of that grungy decode logic for other purposes. What I can't seem to do is to figure out a good way to export my grungy decode logic as an interface that can be used by external classes, *and* also still use it internally to my `UltraDecoder` class without exposing internal details of `UltraDecoder`.

Any suggestions?

```
/** structured metadata */
public interface Metadata { ... }

/**
 * an opaque data item that can be unpackaged
 * to zero or more pairs of (Metadata metadata, int value)
 */ 
public interface DataItem { ... }

public interface SuperDecoder {
   ...
   /** decodes the item and passes each (metadata, value) pair
    *  to a listener by calling its onUpdate() method
    */
   public void decode(DataItem item, SuperDecoderListener listener);
}

public interface SuperDecoderListener {
   public void onUpdate(Metadata m, int value);
}

/* package-private classes implementation classes follow */
class UltraDecoder implements SuperDecoder
{
   static private class SmartObjectWithMetadata
   {
       final private Metadata metadata;
       public Metadata getMetadata();
   }

   private interface UltraDecoderListener
   {
       public void onUpdate(SmartObjectWithMetadata, int value);
   }

   private void ultraDecode(DataItem item, UltraDecoderListener listener)
   {
      /* ... does lots of grungework to obtain 
         the (SmartObjectWithMetadata, value) pairs that correspond to this
         DataItem.

         Calls listener.onUpdate(smartObject, value) zero or more times.
       */          
   }

   public doSomething() 
   { 
      /* ... calls ultraDecode() ... this happens normally */ 
   }
   @Override public void decode(DataItem item, 
       final SuperDecoderListener listener)
   {
      /* ??? how do we leverage ultraDecode ??? 
       * Below, we can do it but we have to create 
       * a new adapter object each time. 
       */
      ultraDecode(item, new UltraDecoderListener() {
         @Override public void onUpdate(
            SmartObjectWithMetadata smartObject,
            int value)
         {
            listener.onUpdate(smartObject.getMetadata(), value);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you do not like about the code above. It looks ok to me.

Comment: Try showing how you would invoke this from an external class, and what "internal details" are unnecessarily exposed from that point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Create a public class DecoderUtil in the same package as UltraDecoder.

```
    public class DecoderUtil {
        public static void decode(SuperDecoder decoder) {
           //do common stuff
           if( decoder instanceof UltraDecoder ){
                //do stuff specific to UltraDecoder
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how that would work. The interfaces are different.

Answer (score 0):

I have myself a hard time in understanding your functional requirement, but it at least sounds like that you simply need a `public abstract class` with some "default" logic already implemented which you can then reuse in subclasses. It's called the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). You see this also practically everywhere in Java Collections and IO API's.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add an overload for onUpdate in UDL that takes an SDL parameter? That being said, I really wouldn't worry about the overhead of object creation unless you *know* it's a problem.